# How to navigate to method from markup?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm used to resharper where you can navigate to a method from the markup by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then click on the method with the mouse.
I'm not using resharper now, and I'm wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut for this in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **F12** to call the **Go To Definition** command, at least on Visual Studio 2008.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/06/04/f12-go-to-definition.aspx